# How to inject a service into a constant in angular

Tags: angular, constants, angular-dependency-injection

I'm trying to export a constant in angular and I need to set a key whose value will be returned from a service. I tried with following code:

This is my user-config.ts file:

```js
export const USER_CONFIG = {
    username: new UserService().getUsername()
}
```

And this is my UserService file that I would like to be injected in constant:

```js
export class UserService{
    constructor(someOtherService: SomeOtherService)
    getUsername() {
        return this.someOtherService.getDetails('some/url')
    }
}
```

I'm not able to work around this problem.
Need help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constants in Angular may be constructed using [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken):

```js
export const USER_CONFIG = new InjectionToken('User Configuration', {
  factory: () => {
    return {
      // You can inject the UserService to get the username
      username: inject(UserService).getUsername()
    }
  }
});
```

Since the constant is an injection token, it can be injected in other parts of your application:

```js
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(USER_CONFIG) config) {
    console.log(config.username)
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptrmbx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have to pass the service instance

```
const va = (userService : UserService) => {
    return {
        username : userService.getUsername()
    }
}

export const eV = va(userService)
```